# No internet connection, can ping fine

Tags: windows, internet, connection, internet-connection

I have multiple devices (Windows 7 PC, Windows Vista laptop, Macbook Air and two phones) at home and a Linksys router. Only Windows 7 PC can't connect to the internet, every other device is fine. More info:

- tried multiple browsers (Chrome and IE). Neither works.
- disabling firewall. Didn't help.
- turning router on/off.
- restarting PC.
- disconnecting and reconnecting all the wires.
- ping google.com: all packets sent and received succesfully.
- browsing straight via IP. No success.
- connecting to my work VPN. Success, can browse. Actually doing that right now.
- ipconfig /all:

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MMPC
>     Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
>     Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
>     IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>     WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
>     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-6F-65-22-E7-F2
>     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::654d:5194:bde8:4b27%10(Preferred)
>     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)
>     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>     Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 2011 m. lapkričio 12 d. 22:33:15
>     Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 2011 m. lapkričio 13 d. 22:33:15
>     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>     DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>     DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 236744549
>     DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-24-7D-07-1C-6F-65-22-E7-F2
>     DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 212.59.1.1
>                                         212.59.2.2
>     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
>     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
>     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>     IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1cbc:130f:b1c7:109e(Preferred)
>     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1cbc:130f:b1c7:109e%11(Preferred)
>     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
>     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{3D3E333A-93BE-4C43-B154-F7BB8347DC4E}:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>     Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
>     Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
>     DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>     Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Comment: Are you sure the ping to Google.com was actually returning a Google IP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the fact that you can access pages through the VPN, and pinging works, but not browsing through IE or Chrome, I am inclined to believe something is wrong with the proxy/VPN settings as Chrome relies/copies/uses Internet Explorer's settings.

Click the `Start Orb` and then in the `search box` type as much of `Internet Options` as you need for it to come in to the search, then click on it.

Go to the `Connections` tab, and click on `LAN Settings`, untick `Use a proxy server for your LAN (These settings will not apply to dial-up or VPN connections).`, also make sure `Automatically detect settings` is ticket and `Use automatic configuration script` is unticked.

[image]

If this doesn't work, let me know as I have a few other ideas - however, I believe that this is the most likely cause.

Comment: Perfect! Very fast, very descriptive (well, maybe a little too descriptive, "Start Orb" ;) ) and very correct answer!

Comment: @MindaugasMozūras - hehe, cool... glad to help! ... Thanks for giving so much information in your question - really helped me zero in on the cause otherwise I would of first suggested a few things such as trying to access sites via their ip.